# How to handle reject in Promise.race() without making the Promise resolve

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to create a function that only runs if a Promise resolves, and do nothing if it rejects or if a timeout is reached.

This is what I have in mind:

```js
onlyRunIfResolvesInTime().then(function(){
   // only run if resolved
})
```

The following code unfortunately always throws a `Uncaught (in promise) two` error when the timeout is reached (`promise2` rejects).

```js
// This promise would be replaced with a function 
// that only can resolve under certain conditions, 
// but if it can't in time we want to reject.
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 500, "one")
})

// This promise is the timeout that rejects if the 
// time limit is reached.
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(reject, 100, "two")
})

let onlyRunIfResolvesInTime = function () {
    return Promise.race([promise1, promise2])
}

onlyRunIfResolvesInTime()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("running function")
    })
```

And if I catch the error in Promise.race() like following

```js
let onlyRunIfResolvesInTime = function () {
    return Promise.race([promise1, promise2])
        .catch(() => { })
}
```

then my `onlyRunIfResolvesInTime` function always resolves and runs the `then` function instead of doing nothing when the timeout is reached.

How can I get `onlyRunIfResolvesInTime` to only run if `Promise.race()` resolves and ignore a reject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ignore the reject handle for `onlyRunIfResolvesInTime`

```
onlyRunIfResolvesInTime()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("running function")
  })
  .catch(() => null) // timed out -> do nothing
```

Comment: Yes, that works. But ist here no other way? I have to use it in several different places and would like to avoid the `.catch()` in order to make my code slimmer and more readable.

Comment: @alev Then pass a good ol' callback to `onlyRunIfResolvesInTime`, and don't return a promise at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a variable:

```
result = promise.then(
        function(v) {
            isRejected = false;
            isPending = false;
            return v; 
        }, 
        function(e) {
            isRejected = true;
            isPending = false;
            throw e; 
        }
    );
function e() {
if(isPending===false){
setTimeout(10, e)
} else if(isRejected===true){
//rejected
} else if(isRejected===false){
//fulfilled
}
}
e()
```